# R CVXR matrix multiplication %*% Error in mul_dims_promote(lh_dim, rh_dim) : Incompatible dimensions

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication, rscript, cvxr

Hello I am trying to run the example from here: http://rtutorial.altervista.org/lp_solvers.html

A snippet and test where it goes wrong:

```
library(CVXR)
#create Variable objects that can be manipulated by the solver.
x<-Variable(3)
#coefficients for objective function
C<-c(2,4,3)

#problem:
C %*% x
```

Error: Error in mul_dims_promote(lh_dim, rh_dim) : Incompatible dimensions

```
> x
[1] "Variable((3, 1), nonneg=FALSE, nonpos=FALSE, pos=FALSE, neg=FALSE, complex=FALSE, imag=FALSE, symmetric=FALSE, diag=FALSE, PSD=FALSE, NSD=FALSE, hermitian=FALSE, boolean=FALSE, integer=FALSE, )"
> C
[1] 2 4 3
> 
> dim(x)
[1] 3 1
> dim(C)
NULL
> 
> class(x)
[1] "Variable"
attr(,"package")
[1] "CVXR"
> class(C)
[1] "numeric"
```

The problem might be in

```
%*%
```

which is defined in three different packages:
Help on topic '%*%' was found in the following packages:

Matrix Multiplication
(in package base in library /usr/lib/R/library)
Matrix manipulation with gmp
(in package gmp in library /home/gnowak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)
Matrix (Cross) Products (of Transpose)
(in package Matrix in library /home/gnowak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6)

Any hints or tips? Thank you.

Comment: Try ‘dim(x)’ and ‘dim(C)’ to see dimensions of your objects. ‘class(x)’ will tell you what R thinks that object is, so check C too.

Comment: Hi, Mark, I added the dim and class output in the question. Thank you.

Comment: So following example on that webpage, the c*x code is within the ‘Maximise’ function - does that work?

Comment: No, it does not work.  I just took the  C %*% x code out to show that the problem is there and not the Maximise function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line `C<-c(2,4,3)` with `C <- matrix(c(2,4,3), nrow = 1)`. That follows the syntax of the later example on that web page, and then that example works for me. The later example now works for me too, (hat tip Jordan) - replace ‘x3 <- Int(1)’ with ‘x3 <-Variable(1, integer=TRUE)’, though the link will probably be updated shortly.

Comment: Thank you, the `C <- matrix(c(2,4,3), nrow = 1) ` works.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you may want to also consider *ROI*, compared with CVXR [here](https://science.data.blog/2018/07/06/optimization-modeling-using-r/)

Comment: Thank you. I don't know ROI I just wanted to compare CVXR with Rglpk. I have used GLPK for years now, but the last release was in 2018 unfortunately.